# Hibernate + Maven + hbm2ddl?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, maven-3

I'm maintaining a project with some Hibernate and a Maven build step do generate some SQL script. That is failing with this error:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection`

Does this just take configuration files or source code annotation configuration and generate SQL script? Why does it need a database? I don't normally have a database setup to build. How do I fix the error?

This is relevant piece from the Maven pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-ddl</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <hibernatetool destdir="target/classes/db_scripts">
                    <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="myPersistenceUnit" />

                    <hbm2ddl export="false" create="true" drop="false"
                            update="true" format="true" outputfilename="GeneratedDdlSchema.sql" />
                </hibernatetool>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: "Why does it need a database?"

Maybe because you are using Hibernate?

Comment: Without databases... there is no sql

Comment: @shinjw hbm2ddl is used to genereate sql schema for creating database, so yes, there is not sql and database at the beginning.

Comment: @clay Take a look at https://github.com/Devskiller/hbm2ddl-maven-plugin